# OR_BIBED_11 error in Google Pay API for Production Environment

Tags: android, production-environment, google-pay, cybersource, merchant-account

I have added the Google Pay API integration and works fine in the Staging Environment.

But when I tried to perform the transaction on Production, it gives me the below error. I tried to search the web for this error code but unable to find anything conclusive. I am using the Cybersource as a payment gateway.

> This merchant is having trouble accepting your payment right now. Try using a different payment method[OR_BIBED_11]

Image:

[image]

Comment: You need to make sure that your app got production approval according to https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/test-and-deploy/request-prod-access - if this doesn't help, follow @GooglePayDevs on twitter and send a message.

Comment: @Domi Thanks to respond on this. How to make it working for the Website ?
 We have added the google pay option in website and we are not able to perform transaction  in website also.

Comment: You have to do the same for you website. If not otherwise mentioned by cybersource, you need to add a Google Pay Web integration to the Google Pay & Wallet console: https://pay.google.com/business/console - if you can share a link to your website I can have a quick look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @Domi's comment, i missed to submit this integration for production access. Once i got the approval from google side, this error disappeared.

Comment: Altough it works in the sandbox environment and altough the web integration has been approved by google we are still getting the error message:  [OR_BIBED_11]. Please help!